# change div content in master page on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

This is a simple question, or not. I have a master page which has three sections, in one section is a logo gallery. There are certain pages in the site i would like to inject text in that area and remove the image gallery, can this be done with jquery in a section within a master page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to access to master page programmatically in your code-behind.

Like this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h(v=vs.100).aspx

On the pages where you don't want to see the image gallery, you could set visibility of that control to false.

Comment: and insert a new div in its place?

Comment: yes, you could find the container control on the master page via the FindControl() method and then add the div to it like this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1304914.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the content with jQuery after the page is loaded (like after clicking a button), you can do that pretty easily. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fq8A/) for a working example.

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#section1").html("new content");
});​
```

Comment: Yes, ty but im still not getting the answer to my question. Can you change div content thats on a master page using the code behind. For example, i have a div in my master page content called "logos". I cannot access it in this manner logos.InnerText I get a red squiggly and intellisense doesn't see it. That leads me to believe I cannot change it in this manner.

Comment: @dinotom, you don't say anything about code-behind in your question, and instead you talk about jQuery, which is client-side, not server-side code. Your question is pretty ambiguous. I highly recommend posting a sample of the code you're having a problem with.

Comment: it can be done either way. I can access the div to make it invisible using this

Comment: Dim c As Control = Me.Master.FindControl("logotransitions")
        c.Visible = False

Comment: but you cannot access the .InnerText. It may just be easier to have another Master Page with that area pre set up and just change the Master Page when necessary in the code